# отметить все условия при которых между главным и придаточым не ставится запятая

Tags: придаточное-предложение

Отметь все условия, при  которых между главным и придаточным предложениями запятая не ставится
1)в цельных по смыслу выражениях
2)в сочетаниях со словом ЧЕМ  без прямого сравнения
3)перед течением союзов и чтобы, и если
4)придаточное состоит из одного союзного слова
5)перед придаточным стоит частица НЕ
6)в сравнительных оборотах со словом ЧЕМ

выберите правильные ответы